# Page load timeout in Selenium

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Sometime my automated test fails because of page load timeout.
I wonder if the issue is not with the website but with my automated test script doing something to the page because:

- Even when I change the page load timeout to 30 sec to say 50, the frequency of the error seems to be about the same
- When I access to the website manually it never takes that long to load a page
- When I kill the automated test while loading the page for a while, it finishes loading and displays the page fine
- Sometime, I can see the page is still loading from the browser tab, but the contents of the page is fully displayed

Has anyone come across to this issue?

**I am using:**

- selenium-java : 2.53.1
- Chrome Driver: 2.30
- Selenide: 4.5

and I use `webDriver.get(url);` method to open an URL in the browser.

**Here is the error trace-back:**

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
>     (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.86)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 50.81 seconds
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$589f8ff4.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c8c4bedf.get()

Comment: Can you update selenium-java to 3.4 and chrome browser too and check?

Comment: Is it always the same page that times out?  Is the page that fails attempting to display data that will vary each time the page is loaded?

Comment: @mandarin You have explicitly mentioned `Chrome Driver: 2.30` but your error stack trace mentions about `chromedriver=2.29.461591`. Try to bump up Selenium to v3.4.0. Thanks

Comment: Have you got an answer? I come across this error intermittently

Answer (score 1):

I faced same kind of issue due to chrome driver incompatibility with selenium.Try to update your chrome driver.

Answer (score -1):

There is no issue with your code. I think you should try updating your Chrome driver to the latest version and see if that issue still come. Please let me know the update.

Comment: This answer doesn't offer anything different than the already existing answer.